# Recursive function in CLIPS

Tags: algorithm, recursion, clips, expert-system

I'm trying to do simple algorithms on clips to get familiar with the language. In this algorithm, I'm trying to make simple recursion calls to calculate the greatest common divisor, but CLIPS breaks every time I try to run it and I don't know why.

```
(deffunction mcd (?a ?b)
  (if (= ?a ?b) then
    (return ?a)
  else if (> ?a ?b) then
    (return (mcd (- ?a ?b) ?b))
  else
    (return (mcd ?a (- ?b ?a)))
  )
)
```

If I enter (mcd 3 3) it works but if a != b CLIPSIDE crashes.

Comment: "CLIPS breaks every time"  meaning what? Any error messages?

Comment: @derpirscher It crashes. no output errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a pair of parenthesis in your `else if (...)` thus your conditions are not evaluated correctly and your code goes into an infinite recursion.

Either remove all the `else` keywords. They are not necessary because you are returing anyways when the condition in the `if` is met ...

```
(deffunction mcd (?a ?b)
  (if (= ?a ?b) 
    then
    (return ?a)
  )

  ;when you arrive here, you know that a != b, 
  (if (> ?a ?b)
    then
    (return (mcd (- ?a ?b) ?b))
  )

  ;when you arrive here, you know a < b
  (return (mcd ?a (- ?b ?a)))
)
```

Or fix your parenthesis

```
(deffunction mcd (?a ?b)
  (if (= ?a ?b) then
    (return ?a)
  else 
    (if (> ?a ?b) then
      (return (mcd (- ?a ?b) ?b))
    else
      (return (mcd ?a (- ?b ?a)))
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: So isn't there a else if clause in CLIPS?

Comment: Most languages don't have an explicit `if .. else if .. else ..`.  There is just a `if .. else ..` and the action in the `else` can again be an `if .. else ..`